# Having issue with document.getElementById when using with HTML5 video player videojs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I'm trying to dynamic load video src for multiple video using one js alone. If i add the js code for individual page it works fine however when combining the js code it doesn't work. Following is my code any help will be appreciated.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />


  <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.11.9/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.11.9/video.js">

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/videojs-contrib-hls/3.0.2/videojs-contrib-hls.js"></script>

</style>
</head>
<body>


  <video class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" controls preload="auto" width="400px" height="400px" 
  data-setup='{}'>
    <source id="videolong" src="" type="video/mp4">
  </video>



    <script>
document.getElementById("videoshort").src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4";
 document.getElementById("videolong").src="https://ia600201.us.archive.org/12/items/BigBuckBunny_328/BigBuckBunny_512kb.mp4";     

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm also using document.getElementById for other info such as txt name and src for img. Following is full code on i'm trying to do it any help will be appreciated.

```
document.getElementById("videoshortname").innerHTML = "ShortVideo";   document.getElementById("videoshortimg").src="http://i.imgur.com/82z3hbN.jpg";
document.getElementById("videoshortmp4").src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4";
document.getElementById("videolongname").innerHTML = "LongVideo";   document.getElementById("videolongimg").src="http://i.imgur.com/PM1qsYT.jpg";
document.getElementById("videolongmp4").src="https://ia600201.us.archive.org/12/items/BigBuckBunny_328/BigBuckBunny_512kb.mp4";
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("videoshort")` returns `null`, because there's no such element, and then trying to access `null.src` throws an error, and nothing works.

Comment: Any advice on how it can be used?